# Are the Shimano BR650 brakes really Ultegra spec?

Tags: road-bike, brakes, shimano

Many ebay and other online vendors advertise the long-reach Shimano BR-650 brakes as being "Ultegra" series.

However, looking at them they don't seem like they are top-of the line or really all that different in manufacture from 105-line Shimano brakes.

The brakes themselves don't seem to say Ultegra on them anywhere but I haven't seen a box for them. Anyone know why they are listed as Ultegra?

Edit: and if they aren't, what series are they? Deores? Altimas? OEMs?

[image: ebay listing]

Comment: I installed one of these yesterday! I'm not impressed... they're very spongy :( Definitely not as good as the 105s they replace, but at least I can align the pads properly.

Comment: I was thinking of up grading from my OEM brakes as well which is why I was looking at them. Guess I'll look at real Ultegras and brake pad extenders.

Comment: Actually, I rode on them today and they had plenty of stopping power, even in the wet. So maybe I was a little harsh earlier. I've also tried a set of Miche brake calipers and they had reach in between the standard and long reach Shimano brakes. They were pretty good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Shimano's website](http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/blevel.jsp?ASSORTMENT%3C%3East_id=1408474395181679&FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302051118), they are non-series components. However, some websites such as [this one](http://roadcyclinguk.com/tech/ultimate-winter-hack-build-part-three-brake-clearance.html) claim they are Ultegra quality (This wouldn't surprise me with Colin's answer). In any case, none of the Shimano long reach calipers are part of a series anymore.

That being said, TRP (e.g. RG957) among others still make high quality long reach calipers if you're willing to pay for them.

Comment: Any idea what pull ratio the RG957 work best with, older style Ultegra (e.g., 6600 and below) or the super SLR pull ratio (6700 and greater)?

Comment: Not sure. My guess is that if theres a slight difference, it would be in favor of the older style. But you may want to email TRP, or maybe someone else will have a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, these brakes have nothing to do with Ultegra.

A lot of unscrupulous Ebay sellers put unrelated keywords into the title to get more search hits. It's against Ebay rules, but it's pretty widespread, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think you will find they are Ultegra, circa something like 2009.  Since the technology trickles down you will find that they look like modern 105's.

Take a look at the CRC product listings for examples of both the modern Ultegra and the old BR-650.

http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/brakes?f=2259

Note: the 2009 is a guess based on comments/reviews found online about that model.

Comment: As Batman has correctly stated below these are non-series Shimano brakes. They are not Ultegra, which has been 6000 series since the 70s. The brakes are simply residual technology and are reliable and cheap. Non-series components are often used for OEM.

Answer (score 2):

These BR-650 is related to the old Ultegra 6500 Series.  Unfortunately, Shimano did not continue with the updating of these long-reach road caliper brakes, if not, there should be the BR-680.